# find the value after a last period

Tags: xslt

I've the below cases in my XML.

```
<item num="1.0.1"/>
<item num="1.0.">
```

i want to capture the first case only as there is a number after the second `.`.

I'm using the below statement to check, but it is true for both scenarios.

```
    <xsl:template name="orderitem" match="item">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(fn:contains(substring-after(substring-after(./@num,'.'),'.'),NaN))">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <li class="item">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>



    </xsl:template>
```

please let me know how can i differentiate these two.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `ends-with(@num, '.')`.

Comment: @user2423959 Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here?

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2 you could use a simple regex

```
<xsl:when test="matches(@num, "^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$")">
```

This will match 3 sets of 1 or more numeric digits separated by a dot.